# Should Mobile and Desktop Versions of a Site Be in Separate Zend Modules?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, mobile, responsive-design

I've inherited a project that is built in a PHP MVC framework (Zend in this case), and is using different modules for the mobile and desktop versions of the site. The project is in early stages (so functionality is only about 20% complete and buggy) and as you may have guessed there is alot of repeated code.

The desktop and mobile sites will have different layouts, although there are common elements. My instinct tells me separating these into different Zend modules is *not* the best approach. I'm thinking I should refactor the code into a single module, and confine the layout differences to views as much as possible. Also, leveraging responsive design as much as possible and only using separate views where necessary (as dictated by my client's requirements). Conceptually I see many advantages to this approach, but being rather new to Zend (and mobile design as well), I'm wondering if I am going to encounter any Zend-specific headaches if I do this refactor (just being a bit paranoid here)?

What is considered "best practice" in general (mobile & desktop co-design)? Any specific advice about Zend MVC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for having modules is to give a way of seperating the model into areas that have different concerns, such as a user section/admin section where you effectively have two different models.

Using modules to seperate between a mobile and desk top version is definately the wrong way to go, you will have duplicate code everywhere. What if you have to support more mobile formats later? You could end up with the same code repeated 3, 4 or more times.

Your instinct is correct, the model will remain the same for mobile or desktop. The controller should decide which view to serve to the client accordingly.

Having this problem will be a good test that you have sepearated your concerns correctly. You should end up with a system that you can drop additional views into with very little effort and with no modification to the model at all.

This is a rather simplistic answer to what is a big subject, but I hope it helps.